# Elasticsearch - query to get latest version of records from a flattened structure

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a scenario where I'd like to return the latest de-normalized data from an index in Elasticsearch grouped by a certain key value - in the scenario below => TradeRef.

The below paints a better picture of data persisted in the index:

```
{"Row": "1", "TradeRef": "A", "TradeRefDate": "2019-01-01 13:00", "TradeRefId": "FFF", "MessageId": "XXX", "MessageStatus": "S-Open"}, 
{"Row": "2", "TradeRef": "B", "TradeRefDate": "2019-01-01 13:00", "TradeRefId": "GGG", "MessageId": "YYY", "MessageStatus": "P-Open"},
{"Row": "3", "TradeRef": "C", "TradeRefDate": "2019-01-01 13:00", "TradeRefId": "HHH", "MessageId": "ZZZ", "MessageStatus": "Q-Open"},
{"Row": "4", "TradeRef": "A", "TradeRefDate": "2019-01-01 14:00", "TradeRefId": "III", "MessageId": "AAA", "MessageStatus": "R-Open"},
{"Row": "5", "TradeRef": "B", "TradeRefDate": "2019-01-01 14:00", "TradeRefId": "JJJ", "MessageId": "BBB", "MessageStatus": "T-Open"},
{"Row": "6", "TradeRef": "A", "TradeRefDate": "2019-01-01 14:00", "TradeRefId": "III", "MessageId": "CCC", "MessageStatus": "R-Open"},
{"Row": "7", "TradeRef": "B", "TradeRefDate": "2019-01-01 14:00", "TradeRefId": "JJJ", "MessageId": "DDD", "MessageStatus": "T-Open"}
```

I desire my query to return the following results where rows 1 and 2 are eliminated because they reference Trade Refs 'A' & 'B' with an older TradeRefDate (2019-01-01 13:00).

More recent rows in the index contain the same TradeRef 'A' & 'B' with a more recent TradeRefDate (2019-01-01 14:00):

```
{"Row": "3", "TradeRef": "C", "TradeRefDate": "2019-01-01 13:00", "TradeRefId": "HHH", "MessageId": "ZZZ", "MessageStatus": "Q-Open"},
{"Row": "4", "TradeRef": "A", "TradeRefDate": "2019-01-01 14:00", "TradeRefId": "III", "MessageId": "AAA", "MessageStatus": "R-Open"},
{"Row": "5", "TradeRef": "B", "TradeRefDate": "2019-01-01 14:00", "TradeRefId": "JJJ", "MessageId": "BBB", "MessageStatus": "T-Open"},
{"Row": "6", "TradeRef": "A", "TradeRefDate": "2019-01-01 14:00", "TradeRefId": "III", "MessageId": "CCC", "MessageStatus": "R-Open"},
{"Row": "7", "TradeRef": "B", "TradeRefDate": "2019-01-01 14:00", "TradeRefId": "JJJ", "MessageId": "DDD", "MessageStatus": "T-Open"}
```

Any assistance will be appreciated. I have tried the below query, but it just gives me one row per TradeRef instead of the matching records associated with the latest TradeRef value:

```
GET /flattened_index_v1/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "TradeRefDate": {
              "gte": "2018-09-01T00:00:00",
              "lte": "2019-10-26T00:00:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "MessageId"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "grp_by_trade_ref": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "TradeRef.keyword",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_trecs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [
              {
                "TradeRefDate": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": {"includes": ["TradeRef", "TradeRefId", "MessageId", "MessageStatus", "TradeRefDate"]}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Do a term aggregation on keyword
2. Do a term aggregation on dates under a keyword. 
   i Select top 1 based on date in descending order
   ii. Return top_hits

```
GET index22/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "TradeRef": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "TradeRef.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "RefDate": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "TradeRefDate",
            "order": {
              "_term": "desc"
            },
            "size": 1
          },
          "aggs": {
            "TopDocuments": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT 1:
You can use (composite aggregation)[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html]

In Composite aggregation you can paginate serially using after_key i.e you can fetch n records then next n records, you cannot jump from page 1 to page 3.

```
GET index22/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "pagination": {
      "composite": {
       "size": 2,  ---> page_size
        "sources": [
          {
            "TradeRef": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "TradeRef.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "RefDate": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "TradeRefDate",
            "order": {
              "_term": "desc"
            },
            "size": 1
          },
          "aggs": {
            "TopDocuments": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 10
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "pagination" : {
      "after_key" : {
        "TradeRef" : "B"    ----> use to fetch next set of records.
      },
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : {
            "TradeRef" : "A"
          },
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "RefDate" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 1,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 50460000,
                "key_as_string" : "1970-01-01 14:00",
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "TopDocuments" : {
                  "hits" : {
                    "total" : {
                      "value" : 2,
                      "relation" : "eq"
                    },
                    "max_score" : 1.0,
                    "hits" : [
                      {
                        "_index" : "index22",
                        "_type" : "_doc",
                        "_id" : "IkBnyG0BwSpwFwW4UeB7",
                        "_score" : 1.0,
                        "_source" : {
                          "Row" : "4",
                          "TradeRef" : "A",
                          "TradeRefDate" : "2019-01-01 14:00",
                          "TradeRefId" : "III",
                          "MessageId" : "AAA",
                          "MessageStatus" : "R-Open"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "_index" : "index22",
                        "_type" : "_doc",
                        "_id" : "JEBnyG0BwSpwFwW4ceBs",
                        "_score" : 1.0,
                        "_source" : {
                          "Row" : "6",
                          "TradeRef" : "A",
                          "TradeRefDate" : "2019-01-01 14:00",
                          "TradeRefId" : "III",
                          "MessageId" : "CCC",
                          "MessageStatus" : "R-Open"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : {
            "TradeRef" : "B"
          },
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "RefDate" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 1,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : 50460000,
                "key_as_string" : "1970-01-01 14:00",
                "doc_count" : 2,
                "TopDocuments" : {
                  "hits" : {
                    "total" : {
                      "value" : 2,
                      "relation" : "eq"
                    },
                    "max_score" : 1.0,
                    "hits" : [
                      {
                        "_index" : "index22",
                        "_type" : "_doc",
                        "_id" : "I0BnyG0BwSpwFwW4V-DW",
                        "_score" : 1.0,
                        "_source" : {
                          "Row" : "5",
                          "TradeRef" : "B",
                          "TradeRefDate" : "2019-01-01 14:00",
                          "TradeRefId" : "JJJ",
                          "MessageId" : "BBB",
                          "MessageStatus" : "T-Open"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "_index" : "index22",
                        "_type" : "_doc",
                        "_id" : "JUBnyG0BwSpwFwW4h-Cq",
                        "_score" : 1.0,
                        "_source" : {
                          "Row" : "7",
                          "TradeRef" : "B",
                          "TradeRefDate" : "2019-01-01 14:00",
                          "TradeRefId" : "JJJ",
                          "MessageId" : "DDD",
                          "MessageStatus" : "T-Open"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wow ... it worked! You are a star :)

The next challenge I have now is how to paginate and sort the thousands of records that come back from this query. Any assistance with this will be very much appreciated. 

I'm aware that I can use 'Partition Aggregation' to break the results into blocks of records, but I understand that that could have its own challenges with memory performance.

Comment: Thanks Jaspreet for your additional updates. The query you provided does limit the TradeRef records by the value passed into the size param, but doesn't limit the hits contained in each TradeRef. I'm guessing this is due to the way ES returns its results in buckets?

Was just wondering if there is a way to combine all the hits within a TradeRef to one bucket and apply sorting and pagination to the combined result-set?

Comment: Top hits supports from, size and sort as in query you can use it for paging the top hits

Comment: Composite aggregation doesn't work on subaggregations. So we cannot create a single bucket from all sub termsl . Your objective can be achieved using composite aggregation+ top_hit from and size.

Comment: Thanks Jaspreet. The challenge I have is that the top_hits sort and size only apply to the values contained at a per bucket level which in this case has been grouped by TradeRef.

If I'm able to combine the values contained in each bucket to a new 'bucket' where I can sort by any field across the combined records, that would be desirable for me. 

Being able to fetch the next batch of records using the 'after_key' was very helpful - thanks again for that.

Comment: I am afraid this cannot be solved using composite aggregation(as it doesn't work on sub aggregations as source). White indexing itself an additional field is added which tells which documents under terms are latest then this can be solved in query part itself. Let me know if you find anything for this

Comment: The alternative to the limitation above is to run two queries => The first query returns the IDs of latest TradeRefs via aggregation on TradeRefDate; The second query takes input from the first query and returns matching records where sorting and pagination are available in the "query" block in ES.

If I can find an efficient way to pass the results of query 1 into query 2 from the server side (instead of pulling the results to the client and sending back up again), that would be desirable. Any thoughts?