# Query unsold products from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticSearch and need some help...

I've an index called sales having these type of records :

```
{product.id : 12 , sales.datetime : October 12th 2019},
{product.id : 13 , sales.datetime : October 12th 2019},
{product.id : 14 , sales.datetime : October 13th 2019},
{product.id : 14 , sales.datetime : October 14th 2019},
{product.id : 14 , sales.datetime : October 14th 2019},
{product.id : 13 , sales.datetime : October 18th 2019},
                             ...
```

I would like to retrieve products unsold from the October 12th 2019,

I tried to filter on the sales.datetime with :

```
"range" => [
             "datetime" => [
                    "lt" => "October 12th 2019"
                ]
            ]
```

But obviously, this type of query will return unexpected values, for exemple with this case, it'll retrieve `product.id : [12,13]` but has you can see, the product.id has been sell on October 18th 2019...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mappings:

```
PUT sales
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "date":{
        "type": "date",
        "format": "MM-dd-yyyy" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "sales",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "I-6Y7W0B_-hMjUaqpQH4",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 12,
          "date" : "10-12-2019"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "sales",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "JO6Y7W0B_-hMjUaqtwEL",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 13,
          "date" : "10-12-2019"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "sales",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Je6Y7W0B_-hMjUaqxgEH",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 13,
          "date" : "10-18-2019"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:-   get max date for all terms, get max date where date range less than 2019-10-12
          if both are same return bucket

```
GET sales/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "transactionId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "maxDate": {
          "max": {
            "field": "date"
          }
        },
        "pending_status": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "date": {
                "lte": "10-12-2019"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filtered_maxdate": {
              "max": {
                "field": "date"   
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "buckets_latest_status_pending": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "filtereddate": "pending_status>filtered_maxdate",
              "maxDate": "maxDate"
            },
            "script": "params.filtereddate==params.maxDate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
 [
        {
          "key" : "12",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "pending_status" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "filtered_maxdate" : {
              "value" : 1.5708384E12,
              "value_as_string" : "10-12-2019"
            }
          },
          "maxDate" : {
            "value" : 1.5708384E12,
            "value_as_string" : "10-12-2019"
          }
        }
      ]
```

EDIT 1:

You can use (top_hits)[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html] aggregation to get all documents in a bucket

```
GET sales/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "transactionId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "id",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "maxDate": {
          "max": {
            "field": "date"
          }
        },
        "pending_status": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "date": {
                "lte": "10-12-2019"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filtered_maxdate": {
              "max": {
                "field": "date"   
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "buckets_latest_status_pending": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "filtereddate": "pending_status>filtered_maxdate",
              "maxDate": "maxDate"
            },
            "script": "params.filtereddate==params.maxDate"
          }
        },
        "top_hits":{   ---> top hits to get all documents under a bucket
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For pagination you can use [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html)/ [include partitions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution, but actually,it does not seem to work... But let me check more in detail and i'll come back. Otherwise, thanks you for your answer

Comment: check for date format and can you add response of above query  might be able to help

Comment: Ok my bad, it works perfectly, one more and last question, if I have a new champ like `saler.id` how to add this champ on the answer ? should i create a new `aggs` in the first `aggs` ?

Comment: You intend to perform aggregation on it or want to get it in out put(top hits aggregation)?

Comment: I would like to retrieve all properties of my object, not only the `id` and the `maxDate` but all other properties like `saler.id` , `price` , ect.... is it possible ? or should I make an aggregation for each of my properties ? No matters where I get it in the response

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. Thanks you

Comment: Glad could be of help

Comment: Pagination will be in two steps. Use composite aggregation it will allow  to paginate terms using after key , for documents in each term you can use from and order in top hits.

Comment: I am not in front of console, it will be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368130/elasticsearch-query-to-get-latest-version-of-records-from-a-flattened-structur/58372644#58372644

Answer (score 1):

Let us take a step back and understand what we are trying to do.

First we want to filter the documents. Secondly we want the filter logic to be `dependent` on the other document's value, which is nothing but a kind of self-join kinda scenario. I don't think that is possible with the way your documents are ingested. You can read more on [join](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html) here.

As a simplest solution, in order to achieve what you are looking for, you would need to change the document structure to something like below. Of course you can also choose to use `nested` type but I think below would be much simpler solution.

### Mapping:

```
PUT sales
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id":{
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "date":{
        "type": "date",
        "format": "MM-dd-yyyy" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST sales/_doc/1
{ 
  "id" : 12 , 
  "date" : ["10-12-2019", "10-18-2019"]       <--- Note this
}

POST sales/_doc/2
{ 
  "id" : 13 , 
  "date" : ["10-12-2019"]
}

POST sales/_doc/3
{ 
  "id" : 14 , 
  "date" : ["10-10-2019", "10-14-2019"]
}
```

### Query:

```
POST sales/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "lte": "10-12-2019"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gt": "10-12-2019"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note how the query has been constructed in a very simplistic fashion using `must` and `must_not` clauses.

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "sales",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 13,
          "date" : [
            "10-12-2019"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that in the response, you get only the document you are looking for.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately i can't change the mapping of my index as it's in a professional context... Should I make an aggregates for each of my records and then make another aggregate to filter on my range time ?

Comment: But now, how to make an aggregation for each of my records ahah, first i should group by `product.id` , then aggregate for each of my records to get the maximum `datetime` value and then aggregate again to filter, but i don't know how to form this type of query... should I make 3 differents query ? I don't think it's optimized....